# c# Directory.GetFiles gives 8.3 file names on drive C

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read files from a directory, but from drive C they are in 8.3 format: ABCDEF~1.EXT. On the other drives it works like a charm.

Some code:

```
String[] newFiles = Directory.GetFiles(outpath);
label1.Text = newFiles[0];
```

Any idea? I don't even know how to search for this problem.

Comment: How is your disk formatted? If it's not NTFS that could be the issue.

Comment: Also, the file naming convention is called the [8.3 format](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

Comment: Both partitions are NTFS.
And thank you for the correction.

Comment: 9.3?  Or 8.3?  Because 9.3 would imply something totally different than 8.3.

Comment: What version of .net?  What OS?  What service packs? What bit-yness?

Comment: Example file: README~1.srt, so it's 8:3.
As for the other questions: .NET 4.5, Win 7 Ult SP1. And uhm.. what is bit-yness? :/

Comment: bit-yness is referring to little or big endian which means the higher order bit is on the left or right respectively. You're prop on little endian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using DirectoryInfo.GetFiles instead of Directory.GetFiles. This returns FileInfo objects which have more meta data about the files. I don't know that this will have any effect, but it's worth trying.

```
FileInfo[] newFiles = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(outpath);
label1.Text = newFiles[0].Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but changing the type from String[] to FileInfo[] gives an error (wrong return type). According to msdn the return type of GetFiles is String.

Comment: @MartinFejes Yes, sorry I left out a detail. It's on the `DirectoryInfo` class, not the `Directory` class. So there is no conversion happening, but I would try the other method. it's far more useful.